# "SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here" calling method in ES6 class

Tags: javascript, super, es6-class

```js
class Foo {
    go() {
        console.log('Foo.go');
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    go() {
        console.log('Bar.go');
        super(); // SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here
    }
}
```

I don't understand, this seems as simple as can be. Banged my head against this for an hour.

Comment: I see many other questions on here about this error message, but they involve different, more interesting problems. Sharing this Q&A to help others new to ES6 classes who may have similarly skimmed the [MDN article on `super`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) and not realized that the example does not show two _alternative_ syntaxes, it shows _required_ syntaxes in different situations.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript invoking the superclass constructor uses the syntax `super()`, but
**for all other methods you must use the syntax `super.methodName()`**.

```js
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.isFoo = true;
    }
    go() {
        this.goFoo = true;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor() {
        super();    // This is correct
        this.isBar = true;
    }
    go() {
        super.go(); // This is correct
        this.goBar = true;
    }
}

const o = new Bar;
o.go();
console.log(o);
// Bar {isFoo: true, isBar: true, goFoo: true, goBar: true}
```

*This is the same syntax as exists in Java, but different from Ruby where `super()` always invokes the same-named method in the parent class.*